# Use Regex ignore timestamps in-between brackets to find duplicate rows and delete them in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to read through lots of logs. When the programming is done incorrectly I can get thousands of lines that repeat the same message but with a different timestamp.  This keeps me from being able to delete duplicate lines through the file because of the variation in the brackets.

Example: Imagine these two lines repeated every 10 seconds or so over the course of the day with useful log information buried between those occurrences.

> [27 Jun 2022 09:47:46 UTC-0400] Disabling override Visonic Control Rm
> Side in dbId 1, sys# 0 with target local
>
> [27 Jun 2022 09:47:46 UTC-0400] Disabling override Visonic Control Rm
> Side in dbId 1, sys# 0 (sent LOCAL_BOX)

I would like to use the 64bit version of Notepad++ so TextFX plugin will not work.

TextViz plugin is broken in the latest versions and requires a lot of steps even when it was working.

Notepad++ Edit/Line Operations/Remove Duplicate Lines will not work because of the time stamp.

Is there a regex command that will allow me to select the error message while ignoring the bracketed timestamp before and then find and remove all duplicate lines?

Comment: Could you just use a regular expression like `\[.*?\] <your error message here>`?

Comment: That appears to be deleting almost every line in the file and leaving the empty rows. Thank you for the suggestion though I'll continue to play around with that.

Comment: Unchecking . matches new line in the settings of ++ resolved the issue where it was deleting almost everything.  Is there a way to have it clear out the empty lines after it does this now?

Comment: you can add the newline character `\n` to the end of the regex so it captures that too. Be careful though - `\`` is a special character in regex so you'll have to escape it. Essentially, just add `\\n` to the end of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that blocks of similar lines are adjacent then doing a regular expression replace-all of `^(\[[^\[\]\r\n]+\])(.*\R)(\[[^\[\]\r\n]+\]\2)+` with `\1\2` will remove all but the first line of a group of adjacent lines.

Explanation

```
^                      Start of line
(\[[^\[\]\r\n]+\])     Capture group 1, the timestamp on the first line
(.*\R)                 Capture group 2, the rest of the first line, including the end-of-line
(                      Grouping for
    \[[^\[\]\r\n]+\]   Timestamp
    \2                 The duplicated text
)+                     This group can be repeated one or more times
```

The replacement text is just a copy of the two parts of the first line.

If the lines are commonly not grouped together then replaceing `^( *\[[^\[\]\r\n]+\])(.*\R)(( *\[[^\[\]\r\n]+\].*\R)*?)( *\[[^\[\]\r\n]+\]\2)+` with `\1\2\3` should work. The extra piece added to the original replace is `(( *\[[^\[\]\r\n]+\].*\R)*?)`. Its outer brackets capture zero or more lines that do not match the first line. This replace would need to be run repeatedly until no changes are made.